# Ignore constructor on deserialize from XML

Tags: xml, vb.net, serialization, constructor, deserialization

I have a class with a List(of SomeKindOfObjects). In the constructor i applied a couple of instances to the list to preset the list for first use. The user can modify the list in the UI. E.g. The user clears out all elements in then list, so that it is empty. After that the Class with the list is serialized to XML.
Later, when i deserialize the XML to the class, the constructor is called and the list is filled again with the "default" values, but it should be empty.

Here are my classes:

```vbnet
Imports System.ComponentModel

Public Class ArticleAndBOMExportEntrySettings
    Implements INotifyPropertyChanged

    Public Event PropertyChanged As PropertyChangedEventHandler Implements INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged
    Protected Sub OnPropertyChanged(ByVal e As PropertyChangedEventArgs)
        RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, e)
    End Sub

    Sub New()
        Me.ExtensionsArticle = New List(Of DocumentType)({New DocumentType() With {
            .Documenttype = DocumentType.EDocumentType.a,
            .Extension = $".{DocumentType.EDocumentType.a}",
            .Name = DocumentType.EDocumentType.a.ToString.ToUpper},
            New DocumentType() With {
            .Documenttype = DocumentType.EDocumentType.a,
            .Extension = $".{DocumentType.EDocumentType.a}",
            .Name = DocumentType.EDocumentType.a.ToString.ToUpper}})

        Me.DbUserArticle = "Test"
    End Sub

    'This is set on deserialze
    Public Property DbUserArticle As String = ""

    'This has always the value set from the constructor, also after deserialize from XML Why?
    Public Property ExtensionsArticle As List(Of DocumentType)

End Class



<Serializable>
Public Class DocumentType
    Implements IEquatable(Of DocumentType)

    Enum EDocumentType
        a
        b
        c
    End Enum
    <Browsable(False)>
    Property Documenttype As EDocumentType = EDocumentType.a

    Public Property Name As String = ""

    <Browsable(False)>
    Property Extension As String = $".{Documenttype}"

    Public Shadows Function Equals(other As DocumentType) As Boolean Implements IEquatable(Of DocumentType).Equals
        Return Me.Name = other.Name
    End Function
End Class
```

How can i ignore the constructor when the xml is deserialized from the XML?
The strange thing on this is: Other properties get set from the XML but not the list. If i do not init the list property from the constructor, everything works fine.

Comment: XmlSerializer requires a parameterless constructor, which is always called when deserializing. Maybe you could empty the constructor, and put the initialization in a separate method you call when you want

Comment: Yes you are right, a parameterless constructor is required. I tried setting the Property using an autosetproperty but the result is the same. Of course i can find a way to set the property with a methode. I will search for a solution like this. But why does it work for the other property and not for the list property. What is the issue in this case?

Comment: By the way, i would say the constructor in the code above is parameterless. ;)

Comment: Yes. It is automatically called, which seems to be your issue. You can remove the code from inside it and put in a method

Comment: But when i the value from deserializing set? If it is called after deserializing, then the value for DbUserArticle Property should also be overwritten but it isn't.